# Creating a Entity Relationship using Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to learn how to use core data, but i got stuck on creating a relationship between two entities, i dont know if i'm looking at this at wrong angle, but basically, i have two Entities: "Listas" and "Tarefas". In my xcdatamodeld, i created a one-to-many relation between the objects, i just dont know how to set the correct relation when adding a "Tarefa".

To my question more clear, here is a image of what i have:

[image: Core Data Relation]

When adding a "Tarefas", object how do i relate it, with the passed "Listas" object?

Thank you!

Comment: Try using a better naming convention for your objects.  Use singular to name the entity e.g. Lista, Tarefa (I have no idea if these are singular names with the same meaning as Listas?).  Then name your relationships in a similar manner, e.g. Lista.tarefas (To-Many), Tarefa.lista (To-One). No need to call the relationship listaTarefas (that's already obvious because its a property of Lista).  Now when you create a new Tarefa 'newTarefa' simply set newTarefa.lista = lista, assuming lista is the passed object.  You don't need to set the inverse relationship.

Comment: Of course this assumes you create NSManagedObject subclasses for your entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same as any other object attribute.

If you **do not** have custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses,

```
Listas *myListas = // passed in
Tarefas *newTarefas = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tarefas" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
[newTarefas setValue:myListas forKey:@"tarefaLista"];
```

If you **do** have custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses,

```
Listas *myListas = // passed in
Tarefas *newTarefas = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tarefas" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
[newTarefas setTarefaLista:myListas];
```

Keep in mind that since you have inverse relationships configured correctly, you only need to make the assignment on one side of the relationship. Core Data will make sure that the other side is also set. So above, I'm only setting a value for `tarefaList`, but the `listaTarefa` also gets a new value.

Answer (score 1):

You could go:

```
Listas* l = //Your passed Listas
Terafas* t = //create your new Terafas
t.terafaLista = l;
```

It would be easier not to call your entities in a plural form (instead of `Listas` call it `Lista`). your code would make more sense.
As @TomHarrington mentioned, your inverse relationship will be automatically maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that people will se this in future, so just in case, this is the code to filter the data based on the relationship between the two objects.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", self.currentListas.listaTarefa];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

self.currentListas is the Lista object passed by the segue.